# Roboguice and mocks: How to have roboguice inject a mock service when testing but use the REAL otherwise?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mocking, mockito, roboguice

Just got my feet wet with roboguice, i like it!

I have quite a lot of methods that depend on a DB and LocationManger etc hence when i am testing these it uses the real objects, i would like to mock these objects so that when i am testing i don't have to depend on anything.

I also have been using mockito but i am unsure how i could go about this?

I know the android system comes with various mocks but i think it would be better to roll my own with mockito?

In either case i need to inject them when testing.

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/blob/master/astroboy/src/test/java/org/roboguice/astroboy/controller/Astroboy2Test.java which uses `Modules.override()` to override the default module with some test-specific configurations.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    // Override the default RoboGuice module
    RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(Robolectric.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(Robolectric.application)).with(new MyTestModule()));
    // For roboguice 4.0 and robolectric 3.1.2
    RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(RuntimeEnvironment.application, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, Modules.override(RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(RuntimeEnvironment.application)).with(new MyTestModule()));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes i see that but still a little confused. For example in my service i have a location manager but its set internally my activity so how i mock somthing that i don't have access to...   Will take another look.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ! I have been looking for this answer quite a lot. It's just sad there is no official documentation on how to inject mocks and other test objects into a Roboguice injected component, testing should be considered with more care in Roboguice documentation.

Comment: This is not a helpful answer at all. The question does not mention Robolectric, yet this answer assumes use of it.

Comment: If you're willing to incorporate Robolectric to get your Mockito mocks working with Roboguice check out this post for a comprehensive strategy. Caveat: I ran into problems using Roboguice 2.0 beta 4. Roboguice 2.0 worked fine. http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2012/09/25/advanced-android-testing-with-roboguice-and-robolectric/

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand on this as it was the top hit while I was looking for it...

Once you've set your test class (or test runner) to override the default RoboGuice module then set your overriden RoboGuice Module as (in this instance)

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(LocationManager.class).toInstance((LocationManager) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));
    }
}
```

Then RoboGuice will inject the same location manager in your tests as in your application. And you can instantiate a shadow of it and set the expected location, provider state, etc.

```
@Test
public void mapLoadsCenteredOnPhoneLocationWhenNoTargetIntent() {
    Location l = new Location("test");
    l.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble("52.222"));
    l.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble("-2.222"));
    shadowLocationManager.setLastKnownLocation(GPS_PROVIDER, l);
    shadowLocationManager.setProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    shadowLocationManager.setProviderEnabled(NETWORK_PROVIDER, false);
            //snip
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Martin: As Paul says you can inject your test location manager with Robolectric and Roboguice. However I think it's better if mocking with Mockito, this [post](http://hintdesk.com/android-basic-testing-with-unit-test-android-test-and-roboguice-robolectric-mockito/) is good for starting. You create a Mocked object and bind it to your interface. You can find also example with mocking and injecting.